# Refresh tokens in Keycloak get invalid after reloading its container

Tags: docker, jwt, nestjs, keycloak, refresh-token

I have a Keycloak Service connecting with my NestJS application, but I've noticed? that after reloading Docker container with Keycloak, my tokens get invalid. Which setting I should change to avoid this?

Connectin KC to DB and saving /opt/keycloak/data/ to volume didn't help.

This is how do I refresh my tokens in NestJS, but I'm sure, that's not the point:

```
const requestBody = {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT,
      client_secret: env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      refresh_token: old_refresh_token,
    };
    try {
      const userCredentials = await this.keycloakAxios.post(
        `${this.keycloakClientRealmUrl}/token`,
        qs.stringify(requestBody),
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        },
      );

      const { access_token, refresh_token } = userCredentials.data;
```